# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' trying to merge a user story to my project

Tags: javascript, express, mern

Hello I know it should be module.exports instead of exports but this doesn't even work and get me error : Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]  any ideas what should I do  I am sorry I am a beginner i have posted the 3 js file of the user story iam trying to add i have added and the server.js file

first .js file.

```
    const scheduleData = require('../models/schedule.js'); 


exports.getschedule= async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const allschedule= await scheduleData.find(); 

        res.status(200).json(allschedules); //Ok
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message}) //Not Founnd
    }
}

exports.createschedules= async (req,res) => {
    const schedule= req.body; 

    const newschedule = new scheduleData(schedule); 

    try {
        await newschedule.save(); 
        res.status(201).json(newschedule); //Created
    
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message}) //Conflict 
    }

} 

exports.deleteschedule= async (req,res) => {
    const id= req.params.id; 


    try {
       await scheduleData.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec(); 
       res.send('Successfully deleted!')
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); 
        
    }

}
```

**Second file**

```
const express = require ('express')
const  { getschedule} = require ( '../../controllers/schedule.js')
const  { createschedule} = require ( '../../controllers/schedule.js')
const  { deleteschedule} = require ( '../../controllers/schedule.js')

const router = express.Router();



router.get('/', getschedule);
router.post('/', createschedule);
router.delete('/:id', deleteschedule);



//export default router;
module.exports = router;
```

**Third fie**

```
 const mongoose = require  ('mongoose'); 

const scheduleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Day: String,
    FirstP: String, 
    SecondP: String,
    ThirdP: String, 
    FourthP: String, 
    FifthP: String,  
    tutorial: {
        type: String, 
        default: 'A'
    },
    
}); 

//const schedule= mongoose.model('schedule', scheduleSchema);
//export default schedule;
module.exports = schedule=mongoose.model('schedule', scheduleSchema);
```

**server.js file**

```
    const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const auth = require('./routes/api/auth.routes.js');
const scheduleroutes = require ('./routes/api/schedule'); 
const courses = require('./routes/api/courses');


const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;


// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true }) // Adding new mongo url parser
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

mongoose.set('debug', true);

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/courses', courses);
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/auth', auth);

app.use('/api/schedule',scheduleroutes);
//app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000/', credentials: true }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are mixing require/exports (CommonJs) with import/export (ES6) syntax. Typically, NodeJs uses [require/exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) when resolving modules. Try to use one consistent style. Can you change to this and see if the error persists:

**first.js**

```js
const scheduleData = require('../models/schedule.js');

// Named exports
exports.getschedule = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const allschedule= await scheduleData.find(); 

        res.status(200).json(allschedules); //Ok
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message}) //Not Founnd
    }
}

exports.createschedules = async (req, res) => {
    ...
}
```

**second.js**

```js
const {getSchedule} = require("./first.js");
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", getSchedule);

module.exports = router;
```

**third.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

const scheduleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Day: String,
    FirstP: String, 
    SecondP: String,
    ThirdP: String, 
    FourthP: String, 
    FifthP: String,  
    tutorial: {
        type: String, 
        default: 'A'
    },
    
}); 

// Default export
module.exports = mongoose.model('schedule', scheduleSchema);
```

Comment: stil getting this error Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
[0]     at Route.<computed> [as post] (C:\Users\Elshazly\Desktop\University-Management-System\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
[0]     at Function.proto.<computed> [as post] 
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Elshazly\Desktop\University-
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Elshazly\Desktop\University-Management-System\server.js:6:24)

Comment: Hmm. Can you edit the post with the new code after you updated, and make sure there is no typo in your code ?

Comment: you are having some typo in the code. The syntax is NOT `exports.export= createschedules= async (req,res)`. It is `exports.createSchedules = aysnc (req, res) =>`. Check out [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) to understand more. Also, on a side note, you can destructure many things at once, so in your second file, you can do `const  { getschedule, createSchedule, deleteSchedule} = require ( '../../controllers/schedule.js')` - one line instead of three

Comment: I am sorry I removed (.export) but still getting same error (edited the code )

Comment: The name is your first file is `createschedules` but then your second file imports `createschedule` (without the final "s"). Can you check that again ?

Comment: Man Thank you u saved my life i appreciate it I am very sorry